# Doing an async call within a dynamicHelper (or some alternative) in Express 2.x

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, express

I'm trying to have a total message count for a user's inbox displayed within my `layout`. I was thinking that I needed to use Express' `dynamicHelpers` to do this, but in Express <= 2.x, these are not async calls, and I need to do some async processing within them: in this case, a database call with a callback.

I'm trying the following to place the count within my session, which itself is put in a `dynamicHelper` accessible to the views. However, due to the asynchronous nature of these callbacks, `session.unreadMessages` is always undefined.

```
messageCount: function(req, res) {
    var Messages = require('../controllers/messages'),
            messages = new Messages(app.set('client'));

    if(req.session.type === 'company') {
        messages.getCompanyUnreadCount(req.session.uid, function(err, result) {
            req.session.unreadMessages = result[0].unread;
        });
    } else if(req.session.type === 'coder') {
        messages.getCoderUnreadCount(req.session.uid, function(err, result) {
            req.session.unreadMessages = result[0].unread;
        });                     
    }

    return;
}
```

Is there another or better way to perform this task?

It should be noted that `req.session.unreadMessages` *is* defined (at least within that callback), but undefined when `session` is called using the helper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure, it it would be a 'best way', but I'm used to using a filter (or a so called middleware) to load data before it reaches the actual destiny, like in:

```
filters.setReqView = function(req,res,next) {
    req.viewVars = {
        crumb: [],
        flash_notice: augument,
    }

    somethingAsync(function(err,data){
        req.viewVars.someData = data
        next()
    })
}

app.all('*', filters.setReqView )


// then on my request:
...
res.render('auth/win', req.viewVars )
```

Refactoring your code you would have:

```
app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
    if(req.session && req.session.type){
        var Messages = require('./controllers/messages'),
            messages = new Messages(app.set('client'));

    if(req.session.type === 'company') {
        messages.getCompanyUnreadCount(req.session.uid, function(err, result) {
            req.session.messageCount = result[0].unread;
            next();
        });
    } else if(req.session.type === 'coder') {
        messages.getCoderUnreadCount(req.session.uid, function(err, result) {
            req.session.messageCount = result[0].unread;
            next();
        });                     
    }
    } else {
        next()
    }
});
```